# show counter while application is in background

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I'm making an application that listening on a UDP socket all the time, even if the application is in the background. when a certain data arrived throw the socket, I want to show the user timer that count 10 seconds from 10 to 0.

is it possible to show this counter while the application is in the background?

can I show the user any message in the background (except `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:...]` that not good for me), like apple alarm clock?

**note**

- I don't need the application to be approved for app store. I just need it to work at home.
- I already successfully keeping the communication in the background and I know that the application running

thanx

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the badge icon, and updating the number from 10 to 0 every second. I'll assume you put these methods in the `AppDelegate`, but they could go anywhere. Try:

**.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
  int       _countDownNumber;
  NSTimer * _countDownTimer;
}
```

**.m**

```
- (void)updateTimer; {
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:_countDownNumber];
  _countDownNumber--;

  if(_countDownNumber < 0){
    [_countDownTimer invalidate];
  }
}

- (void)methodThatStartsTheCountDown; {
  _countDownNumber = 10;
  _countDownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Hope That Helps!

Comment: Is it OK, review-wise to use the badges like that?

Comment: I have no idea, I've never tried it. He did mention that he didn't need it to be approved though.